# Max and min on date input

Tags: validation, angular, datepicker

How do I make restrictions on my date input in Angular 2? My code currently looks like this:

```
<input #birthday="ngModel" type="date" name="birthday" max="2012-12-12" min="2000-12-12" required ngModel>
```

The following date should be invalid, but it isn't:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What browser(s) are you testing this with?

Comment: @R.Richards Google Chrome :)

Comment: On input type date we can use either min or max one of them only reference W3schools

Comment: no you can use both.

Comment: Looks like you can still type in any date, only the date picker will be limited to the min/max timeframe. Validates on submit, though.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that it is showing is valid because the only validation you have is if it's **required** so the input is valid. Setting the max and min date only limit the input for the date. If you try to submit you should probably see an error such as this

[image]

If the above behavior is not enough since you are seeing the input as valid, you will need a custom validator. From your code, it seems like you are using a template driven form. Adding a custom validator to a template driven form is a little more complex but you can still do it. Here is a link to a tutorial for adding a custom validator to a template driven form

https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/ng2-template-driven-form-validators/

**NOTE**

Be careful with the date input type as it is not supported in a lot of browsers. You should probably look at angular calendar components such as PrimeNG calendar.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Do you have any suggestions as to how to do this without the date input?